# Value of type INTERFACE_HEAD() cannot be converted to INTERFACE_HEAD()

Tags: vb.net, soap, saprfc

I want to connect with SOAP to SAP and have received a `WSDL` file. After import of the file as a Service Reference `SOAPService` I've now these classes available:

```
SOAPService.IMPORT1
```

Namespace `myComp.SoapSap`

```
myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_HEAD
myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_POS
myComp.SoapSap.IMPORT
```

I'm new to `SOAP` and `SAP` and do not know how to connect through `SOAP` to `SAP`. This is what I've done so far:

```
Dim soapClient As New myComp.SoapSap.IMPORT
Dim soapHead(1) As New myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_HEAD
Dim soapPos(1) As New myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_POS
Dim client2 As New SOAPService.IMPORT1

soapClient.Url = "http://" & AppServer

Dim Cred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential(User, Passwd)
soapClient.Credentials = Cred

client2.IV_PRODUCT = "/MYCOMP/ABCD"
client2.IV_IMAGE = Convert.FromBase64String(base64_doc)
client2.IV_FILENAME = _batch.UserProperty("Filename")
client2.IV_EML = Nothing

soapHead(0) = New myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_HEAD
soapHead(0).FIELD = "testheadfield"
soapHead(0).VALUE = "testposfield"

soappos(0) = New myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_POS
soappos(0).FIELD = "testposfield"
soappos(0).VALUE = "testposvalue"
soappos(0).LINE = "testposline"

client2.IT_HEAD = soapHead 'Error see below

soapClient.IMPORT(soapHead, soappos, client2.IV_EML, client2.IV_FILENAME, client2.IV_IMAGE, client2.IV_PRODUCT, client2.IV_REIMPORT) 'Error 404
```

Description of the Error:

`client2.IT_HEAD` Mouseover: `(field) Exp.SOAPService.IMPORT1.IT_HEAD As Exp.SOAPService.INTERFACE_HEAD()`

`client2.IT_HEAD = soapHead()` Error: `Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array`

`client2.IT_HEAD = soapHead(0)` Error: `Value of type 'INTERFACE_HEAD' cannot be converted to  'INTERFACE_HEAD()'`

`client2.IT_HEAD = soapHead` Error: `Value of type INTERFACE_HEAD() cannot be converted to INTERFACE_HEAD() because INTERFACE_HEAD is not derived from INTERFACE_HEAD`

When I try to run `soapClient.IMPORT()` I get a `404` error. Anybody knows how to do a proper connect and what `client2.IT_HEAD` expects as a value? Have I declared the array `soapHead()` wrong?

Comment: You appear to have two different types with that name. Your variable is type `myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_HEAD` while the field you're trying to assign to is type `Exp.SOAPService.INTERFACE_HEAD`. You need to use just the one type.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks, that works. Do you know what is the difference between `myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_HEAD` and `Exp.SOAPService.INTERFACE_HEAD` and why do I have two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myComp.SoapSap.INTERFACE_HEAD` and `Exp.SOAPService.INTERFACE_HEAD` are in two different namespaces. Therefore the error: `Value of type INTERFACE_HEAD() cannot be converted to INTERFACE_HEAD()`